# Download cloudera docker image manually

Tags: hadoop, docker-machine, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I was hoping to install cloudera docker image on my laptop, It says that the file is about 4gb, I have a slow internet connection so i searched for downloading the image manually, I found - http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html

[image]

In the above image it says that we can download the image from the website.
So I went to http://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-7.html selected docker image as the Platform and Signed In and then clicked on Download Now.

It says that your download will start automatically, or CLICK HERE, 
and then it redirects me to https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/, even in the page source its the href of the link. Can anybody help me with the download link.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil, the procedure is to import the image from Docker Hub (there is no "download" from cloudera.com). Instructions are provided via https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/.